# Efibootmgr command for OS X

Tags: command-line, dual-boot, efi

I have successfully been able to install Linux Mint on my Mac. The only issue is I cannot select the boot partition holding <kbd>option</kbd>. To fix it I booted into linux and ran `sudo efibootmgr -o 1,80`. This forced my Mac to boot into Linux. This now forces me into Linux but I have to old down <kbd>option</kbd> to boot back onto OS X.

Question is, is there a similar command to `efibootmgr` for OS X? This way I will be able to create a shortcut for booting into Linux and OS X. Currently the option key does not detect Linux but rEFInd does. Is there a command tool that allows be to boot into the other option like efibootmgr or not on OS X? I guess `bless` cannot do it otherwise we would see it on the boot screen.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to this is ***yes***.

I answered a very similar question related to Ubuntu.  Your command set the boot order as Linux then (I am assuming here) Mac OS X.  What you have to do is set the boot order to boot the OS X partition first and you can do this in System Preferences.

Have a look [at this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230010/boot-problem-on-dual-boot-macbook-pro/230025#230025) as it should be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I would have preferred to post a comment against Allan's answer.  However, as I don't have enough reputation to do so, here is an answer.

The short answer is actually NO.  OSX does not see the EXT4 partition and therefore you can't choose it in `System Preferences -> Startup Disk`.

The long answer is to boot from a Live Ubuntu CD (or USB) and use its `efibootmgr` to change the boot order.

I am using rEFInd as my boot manager, and each time I do an OSX update or get a Ubuntu kernel update, I have to go through this procedure. *Ubuntu kernel updates change the boot order these days*

Answer (score 0):

You have to have something on a UEFI built-in driver readable volume (HFS/FAT) - then you can use:

https://github.com/vulgo/bootoption