# Boot problem on dual-boot MacBook Pro

Tags: terminal, command-line, unix, dual-boot

Can anyone help me restore the original boot 'order' on my Mac, using command-line?

I wanted to install Ubuntu on my Macbook Pro Retina (early 2013), so I could run some specific software I needed for my work. I followed the instructions from this site: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-linux-macbook-pro/

I managed to install Ubuntu on a small partition on my HD, and then I performed 'efiboot fix', as suggested, so I could boot Ubuntu after restarting my Mac. I ran the following commands in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install efibootmgr
sudo efibootmgr
sudo efibootmgr -o 0,80
```

Then I restarted my Mac, but neither Ubuntu nor OS X could boot normally. Basically, I got a blank screen. I restarted again, holding the alt key, and then I was able to choose to boot OS X.

Can I revert the boot order somehow, using Terminal commands in OS X? Really don't feel like experimenting again with Ubuntu. And can I remove this disk partition with Ubuntu now? I tried to do it through Disk Utility, but it's not possible. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please issue the command `sudo efibootmgr` and past the output to the question.

Comment: If you prefer, I could post how to boot Ubuntu by holding down the alt/option key at startup.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can boot into OS X by holding down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key and selecting your OS X partition, you just need to set the Startup Partition in System Preferences.

[How do I set OS X to boot by default?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38572/how-do-i-set-os-x-to-boot-by-default)

This will be persistent across reboots.

Comment: Thanks @Allan. However, recently my computer crashed, and I had to use internet recovery to install new OS. The new OS was installed on a smaller partition of my SDD, and the main partition (macintosh HD, now disk0s2) was not available. Later, in Disk Utility, I saw that it was  'not mounted'. 
Do you have any advice on how to fix this, to mount this partition? 
If not, can I at least recover some files?